X509Certificate2 class, error in the production environment only
I need help resolving an issue with importing a .p12 certificate: When I use
new X509Certificate2(certificado)

it works in the development environment, but it throws an error when I run it on the server. The certificate is a byte[] containing the certificate.
The error on the server is:

System.Security.Cryptography.CryptographicException: The specified network password is not correct.

The certificate has no password, and if I use it from the development environment, it can instantiate the class without the password.
I need to publish this process on a Windows Server 2022 with IIS .NET Framework 4.8
Any idea what could be causing this?

I wonder if there is a Windows setting that disallows certificates without a password in your production environment.

try like this new X509Certificate2(certificado, String.Empty, X509KeyStorageFlags.MachineKeySet);
